# Is it possible to create this new IOS Modal View in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is what I'm talking about: (this is taken from the Elgato Control Center App)

**iPhone**

| before popup | after popup |
| --- | --- |
| [image: before popup] | [image: after popup] |

**iPad**

| before popup | after popup |
| --- | --- |
| [image: before popup] | [image: after popup] |

Any pointers are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on your definitions of terms.

If you think precisely using only Xamarin.Forms and using native pop-ups that you have shown, the answer is no.

If you are fine with using some non-native pop-ups, then you can read Wen xu Li's answer (but I would say you it doesn't fit your request well).

Finally Xamarin.Forms is built on top of Xamarin.iOS where such thing is possible. You can access Xamarin.iOS project and technically you can do this. I think this should be possible with a custom renderer.

Comment: Would that mean having different (for example) settings pages for IOS and Android? So I would have to code out the native IOS one and then another one for Android? If so, I don't really understand how this is done, is there a blog/docs page on how to split between the IOS and Android versions of the app?

Comment: @nick if you search for custom renderer you should find a lot of posts regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an example using Rg.Plugins.Popup.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<pages:PopupPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    x:Class="App2.Page1">
    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation
            PositionIn="Bottom"
            PositionOut="Bottom"      
            DurationIn="400"
            DurationOut="300"
            EasingIn="SinOut"
            EasingOut="SinIn"
            HasBackgroundAnimation="True"/>
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <StackLayout
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Frame CornerRadius="20"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="200" >
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="This is popuppage"></Label>
                <Button Text="close" Clicked="Button_Clicked" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

Here is the cs code:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Page1 : Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages.PopupPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PopPopupAsync();
    }
}
```

Add in MainActivity of Android:

```
Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this);
```

Add in AppDelegate of IOS:

```
Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
```

Here is the running screenshot:

[image]